# Can an about-to-be-killed medical be stopped for Emergency Treatment of another personnel

Tags: star-trek-ccg

I play an [Ardent Predator](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=3412) and my opponent fails to meet the criteria so two personnel are selected to be killed.

(Example: A [E.M.H. Program](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=1174) and a [Picard](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=337))

None of the non-selected personnel has medical.

Can my opponent use [Emergency Treatment](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=752) (or any other card that requires a present medical)?

On the one hand, while the effect of Emergency Treatment takes place (When a unique personnel is about to be killed) takes place, the med is not yet killed. On the other hand the med is also about to be killed, so shouldn't be able to do something.